# iOS Universal App files only for iPad or iPhone

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-universal-app

When I name a file ~ipad or ~iphone will they only be bundled into the apps for the specific devices or into both?
If both how can I achieve that a file is only compiled with the iPad or iPhone version?
Thank you, a0down

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the main features of a universal app is that the binary is the same for both iPhone and iPad. What you submit to the app store is a single binary that contains all the assets and code required to run the app on both devices.

Unfortunately the only way for you to get what you want would be to create two completely separate apps - one for iPhone, one for iPad - and submit them both to the store.